# Is it possible to run Cucumber and JUnit tests simultaneously using Mockito with 'mvn test' command in Java?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, cucumber

How to execute Cucumber's tests (annotated with @When, @Then, etc) and JUnit unit tests (annotated with @Test) in same 'mvn test' execution?

I can execute all Cucumber's tests OR all JUnit unit tests. What about both? Im expecting have a folder with features files and a folder for steps to them and another folder with all unit tests (only using Mockito and @Test annotated methods).